# Notepad++ Autocomplete define your own special words

Tags: notepad++, autocomplete, xml

I heard that Notepad++ has autocomplete option but I can't find any documentation online to help with creating your own or how to do it. 
I would like to define words for autocomplete .
for example every time I write "dog" i would like notepad to offer me to complete this word to "dog and cat "If somebody could please point me in the right direction (or right out tell me, that's always nice), I would truly appreciate it!

Thanks if you can!

Answer (score 2):

You can find settings by follwing the below:

```
Settings -> Preferences -> Auto-Completion -> Enable auto-completion on each input.
```

There is also a wik dedicated for autocomplete in notepadd++

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion

The AutoComplete files are located in the `plugins\APIs` folder, to be found in the Notepad++ Install Folder, most often `C:\Program Files\Notepad++`

The syntax of AutoComplete files is simple, but does have a few rules, most importantly correct syntax and proper sorting. If the syntax is incorrect, the XML file will fail to load and AutoComplete will be disabled. A more formal description can be found at Editing Auto Completion files.

Improper sorting can cause the AutoComplete function to behave erratic, causing it to fail on certain words.

The basic character set used to recognise keywords is made of letters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 digits and the underscore. In future release of Notepad++, you will be able to add more characters - the dot is a likely candidate - by specifying the additionalWordChars parameter in the environment. The value will be a string with all the extra parameters without any separators. However, this additionalWordChars is still not working (Notepad++ v.6.5.2)!

Syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>
<NotepadPlus>
   <AutoComplete language="C++">
       <Environment ignoreCase="no" startFunc="(" stopFunc=")" paramSeparator="," terminal=";" additionalWordChar = "."/>
       <KeyWord name="abs" func="yes">
           <Overload retVal="int" descr="Returns absolute value of given integer">
               <Param name="int number" />
           </Overload>
       </KeyWord>
   </AutoComplete>
</NotepadPlus>
```

Comment: already sow this doc and still can't understand how can i make my notepadd++ to auto compleate me every time i write "dog" to "dog and cat"

Comment: @David If you want to replace `Dog` with `Dog and Cat` every time, you can also use `AutoHotKey`. This software is free. And it woks not just with `Notepad++` but for every software installed on system.

Comment: The link for the docs seems broken/outdated. This appears to be the new link: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/auto-completion/